# Python & Flask error using Flask-MySQL | Module Not Found Error: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Tags: python, sql, flask, error-handling, flask-mysql

In my system,  I installed the `flask_mysqldb`, however when I run the `app.py` file it shows an error like `nomodule named flask_mysqldb`.

I tried another way of downloading `mysqlclient` and installed it, but the same error occurs.

### Error

```py
The error is  line 2, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

I would appreciate a solution, thanks.

Comment: You should add More information. 1. Ide you are using . 2. Does this happen only with flask_mysqldb , is there Flask or other packages installed and don't work? .3 how did you install flask_mysqldb ? with pip?

Comment: Also which Operating system are you using?

Comment: 1.no ide in cmd I run it
2.no flask is working
3.with pip I installed flask_mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

After some research I can suggest you to do the following:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Another way to connect and define your credentials to MYSQL would be:

```py
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Finally:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Documentation**

[Mysql Flask Documentacion Oficial](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: line 3, in <module>
    from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskext'                                                                          Getting this error when I used above solution

Comment: @KSM I made the code more simple, it works for me Are you sure you run `pip install flask-mysql` ?

Comment: The same code which I used is now running in pycharm. In cmd prompt only there is a problem.Thank you